# Use a text field to set the title of an MKAnnotation in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, mkannotation

having registered a long press at a point on the map, I'd like a text field to pop up, so I can set the input as the title of a pin dropped at that point. How would I go about doing this?
Heres my code which currently registers a longpress and drops a pin, that all works fine! I'm not sure how to bring up a text field and get the users input though

```
func DropPin(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
     if gestureRecognizer.state == .Began {

        var point:CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.Map)

        var pinLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.Map.convertPoint(point, toCoordinateFromView: self.Map)



        let x = CustomAnnotation(coordinate: pinLoc, title: "Pin", subtitle: "Pin", imageName: "TouchPin")
        self.Map.addAnnotation(x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do so, but you can choose one of the two for example.

In your view, you add a text field where the user set the title before you drop the pin. But that might not be intuitive or look bad (if you need to have a full screen map for example).

So, what I would suggest is to fire an [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) with a text field inside. [Here is an example](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/) of how you could do it.
Either you :

1. Create the annotation
2. Add it to the map
3. An alert appear
4. The user enter a name (keep it somewhere)
5. You retrieve the last annotation you've added
6. You set it's title with the name entered previously

Or :

1. You detect your long press
2. An alert appear
3. The user enter a name (keep it somewhere)
4. Create your annotation with the name entered previously
5. Add it to the map

Those are just 2-3 examples. You might think of something else :)

Comment: Thanks! Using the UIAlert is a great solution! (And I was hoping  if I could avoid having text fields where the user has to preset the title as I felt it'd be more intuitive having it pop up)